# Android : How to find contact name and number from recipient_ids

Tags: java, android, android-studio, contacts

I am using

```
Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms, null,null,null,null);
    cursor.moveToLast();
    while  (cursor.moveToPrevious())
    {
        String recipient_ids= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("recipient_ids"));
        String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("snippet"));

     }
```

to get a list of sms conversation.
The "recipient_ids" returns some value Like 302, 301 259 etc. What I want is a function where i will pass the "recipient_ids" as perameter and it will return the display name of the contact (If available else the Number)

Answer (score 2):

These methods help you to achieve what you want:
getContactByRecipientId - to get contact number by recipientId.
getContactbyPhoneNumber - to get display name by phone number.

```
public String getContactByRecipientId(long recipientId) {

   String contact = "";
   Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/canonical-address"), recipientId);
   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

   try {
     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contact = getContactbyPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(0));
    }
  } finally {
    cursor.close();
  }

  return contact;
}


public String getContactbyPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {

  Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
  String[] projection = {ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NORMALIZED_NUMBER };
  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

  String name = null;
  String nPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;

  try {

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      nPhoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NORMALIZED_NUMBER));
      name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }

  } finally {
    cursor.close();
  }

   if(name != null){ // if there is a display name, then return that
      return name;
   }else{
      return nPhoneNumber; // if there is not a display name, then return just phone number
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code

```
    private void fetchInbox() {
    Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    String[] reqCols = new String[]{"_id", "address", "body"};
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
            new String[]{"body", "address"}, new int[]{
            R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber}, 0);
}
```